# Strange intermittent Paypal issue assigning old order numbers

Tags: invoice, paypal-express, ce-1.9.3.1

This issue started 14 days ago for what we can see no apparent reason. When some customers choose to pay via PayPal (Express Checkout) they are able to pay, but the order is not created in Magento and PayPal has an old / already used invoice ID.

How can this happen? Thought it was impossible for magento to reissue Order / Invoice IDs

Comment: Do you have any extensions that allow custom order numbers?

Comment: we do have Fooman Order Number Customiser but we've had it for years.

Comment: we had a similar situation while ago (different extension). Was working fine for ages and then suddenly it started trying to use Order/invoice IDs that had already been allocated. Removed the extension and the problem hasn't occurred since. (Sorry, I don't have a solution other than that)